# Unable to paginate releases in GitHub V3 API

Tags: github, github-api

I'm trying to list all of the releases of a public repository on GitHub using their V3 API. Here's the request I'm making:

```
curl -is -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json' \
    https://api.github.com/repos/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/releases
```

The response headers I receive back are here:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Fri, 29 Jan 2016 20:23:15 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 29612
Status: 200 OK
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 19
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1454099558
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60, s-maxage=60
ETag: "947039722a1073c5279a9fd39d00c0bf"
Vary: Accept
X-GitHub-Media-Type: github.v3; format=json
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, Link, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Served-By: b0ef53392caa42315c6206737946d931
X-GitHub-Request-Id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Notice the lack of the `Link` response header? In the response body, I only get back around 7 releases and I can't seem to paginate forward or backward by manually specifying the `?page=N` query parameter.

For some background, FFmpeg has about 226 releases present [in its GitHub repository](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/releases), and I'm only getting around 7 of those, unable to paginate through them.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here that would limit my responses back from the GitHub v3 API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub conflates its proprietary Releases feature with regular Git tags. Many of the "releases" that you see for ffmpeg are actually just tags.

Here is an [example of a real release](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/releases/tag/n2.5.4). Note how it contains much more information than [a tag does](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/releases/tag/n2.5.10). Despite their web UI showing tags mixed in with releases, GitHub's [release API endpoint doesn't include regular tags](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#list-releases-for-a-repository):

> This returns a list of releases, which does not include regular Git tags that have not been associated with a release. To get a list of Git tags, use the [Repository Tags API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-tags).

Using the [tags endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-tags) as GitHub suggests gives more results, and includes a `Link` header as you expect:

```
curl -is -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json' \
    https://api.github.com/repos/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/tags
```

Comment: So you're saying that the GitHub releases page on the web is just showing tags that were never made into releases, hence there's a discrepancy between the releases vs. tags in the API?

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay, it shows both. Use the **Next** link to go back a few pages (another weird UI issue, I think) and you'll see a real release mixed in with the tags. I'm not sure why they do this.

Comment: Confusing AF IMO. The discrepancy is that the web UI does something different than the API does.

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay, I agree. This is one of GitHub's worst-designed features IMO.